# How to use the UiScrollable function in Appium when the scrollIntoView text object is passed through a variable?

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, appium

If the country i.e. Algeria is directly passed in place of country in quotes, it works fine, however, if the variable is used, an error pops up.

Please suggest how to scroll and find an element, when the element is in a variable.

```
String country = "Algeria";
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(country))").click();
```

> Error: Could not parse expression new UiScrollable(new uiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(country)): 'UiScrollable' doesn't have suitable method 'scrollIntoView' with arguments [text(country)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
String country = "Algeria";
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"" +country +"\"))").click();
```

Comment: H, I got it now. There needs to be one extra pair of quotes in your code.

Comment: @WiaN the main issue you're facing is concatenate string, you should mention in the question if you want to use quotes, but you didn't do it. Answer updated.